# How can I toggle mouse scrolling behavior while screen is already running?

Tags: gnu-screen, mouse, scrolling, konsole

Right now I have the following line in my `~/.screenrc` so I can scroll back and see the output for a screen window:

```
termcapinfo xterm ti@:te@
```

Now that I am editing in `vim`, I would like to use my mouse for scrolling *inside* vim, not in the terminal scrollback. Is there a way to disable the terminal scrollback at runtime?

The `screenrc` manual page mentions that `termcapinfo` cannot be changed once started:

> You have to place these commands in one of the screenrc startup files,
>   as they are meaningless once the terminal emulator is booted.

... so that cannot be relied on. Reasonable hacks are also fine, I am using the Konsole terminal emulator.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a workaround specific to vim (i.e. it does not work for `less` for example):

- [Save undo history](https://askubuntu.com/a/4247/6969).
- [Use sessions to save opened tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1642641/427545).
- Close vim.
- Detach screen.
- Re-open vim (or open a screen with termcap disabled).

Commands (`:foo` is a vim command, the others are shell):

```
mkdir /tmp/vimundo
:set undodir=/tmp/vimundo undofile
# note: `set undofile` has to be done for each tab and is saved only
# when the file itself is saved.
:mks /tmp/sess.vim
:wqa
```

You can put the `undodir` and `undofile` directives in your vimrc for the future so you do not have to repeat. I haven't done that yet, so to reattach my vim session and keep the undo history:

```
vim -S /tmp/sess.vim +set\ undodir=/tmp/vimundo\ undofile
```

Comment: I am still looking for a general approach for `screen` that works also for, say, `git log` (less pipe).

Comment: I think the only general workaround is to have 2 different screen sessions, by running `screen -c /dev/null ...` to ignore the termcapinfo line in `~/.screenrc` when we need the application mode.